# How to make a screensaver for windows 7 c++

Tags: c++, windows-7, screensaver

I realize the above is not so much a specific question, and I have no code to speak of, but I feel that others also have been unable to accomplish this feat - it strikes me as one of those problems where case can be everything.

So here lies my problem. I have made the screensaver, per say, of what actually runs. Essentially what I want to do is, make it run, by itself, off the timer... and perhaps some of the associated preview window features, because we need to get it selected. Problem is, either the resources regarding this are scare, by case, or my Google-fu is just not working today. (virtually all screensaver tagged questions I found on SO were about users who either knew how to make a screensaver, or those who wanted to not make one but check on one, i.e if it started running during program execution.

Some info: Trying to make it for windows 7 (using windows 7 if it matters) using C++.

What I am asking is, how to get from my current point, where I have a normal program (i.e, start in main, do some graphics...) which loops fine by itself, but I am trying to figure out, how to make it an actual screensaver - which, unfortunately, cannot be  solved simply by renaming it .scr.

Thanks if you can provide any information.

PS: I am pretty new here, and don't know to much about most things, including using SO. My last question was downvoted (I will admit, it was bad), and I am now determined to ask good questions.

Comment: Here is a good introductory article with code -http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1551/Creating-a-screen-saver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should help:
http://www.cityintherain.com/howtoscr.html

and another (with downloadable example code)
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/opengl/article.php/c2695/OpenGL-screen-savers.htm

i hope you're familiar with the win32 api

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry my response took to long, I was trying this out. Unsucessfully, I might add. I have no experience with the win32 API.  Cannot seem to get rid of the errors... One thing I am wondering about is the timer, and what you put under it. My guess is that the code under it is executed every timer period, but what happens if it does not finish that quickly? Currently, I cannot fix this linker error... Hrm. Apparently the System32 folder is protected, although that makes sense.

Comment: I never got this to work, but on looking back at this post (was a bit frustrated at the lack of screensaver-ness before), you did provide helpful sources, mostly the first one. As such, I decided to give you the accept. Sorry. I think I will try looking at MSDN and see if I can Google up some Win32 API tutorials, because to me it is a mess, but maybe I will figure it out and get this working.

Comment: This post is more a comment than an answer.